# How to use Autocomplete Widget and get Value from selected Map Options

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, widget

The purpose of my developpement with FLutter is to suggest the **label** String from this kind of dataSet BUT query an API with the corresponding **value** :

```
List<Map<String, String>> dataTradList = [
  {"label": "frName1", "value": "engName1"},
  {"label": "frName2", "value": "engName2"},
  ...
];
```

Here is a snippet of  the AutoComplete Widget i'm setting up,

```
Autocomplete<String>(
              optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
                if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
                  return const Iterable.empty();
                }
                return dataTradList
                    .where((element) {
                      String label = element['label']!.toLowerCase();
                      return label.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
                    })
                    .map((option) => (option['value']!))
                    .toList();
              },
              onSelected: (option) {
                setState(() {
                  query = option;
                });
                print(query);
              },
            ),
```

As Expected, the options suggested by this code is the engNameX, the query takes value of engNameX when option is selected and it could be ok like that

What i want to achieve now is to make the suggestion with the frNameX **BUT** set the query with the corresponding engNameX just for the user convenience, i was able to achieve this in js but i don't know how to do this in Flutter

Answer (score 0):

tyr this code to make the suggestion with the frNameX BUT set the query with the corresponding engNameX just for the user convenience

```
   Autocomplete<Map<String, String>>(                 // <--- change here
    optionsBuilder: (TextEditingValue textEditingValue) {
      if (textEditingValue.text == '') {
        return const Iterable.empty();
      }
      return dataTradList.where((element) {
        String label = element['label']!.toLowerCase();
        return label.contains(textEditingValue.text.toLowerCase());
      }).toList();                                   // <--- change here
    },
    onSelected: (option) {
      setState(() {
        query = option["value"];   // <--- change here "value" or "lable" as required
      });
      print(query);
    },
  )
```